# DevAzure Поделиться доступом к проекту

Tags: visual-studio, azure, devops, azure-devops

Как пользоваться DevAzure ?
Необходимо делиться репозиториями, на сайте написано, что +5 человек бесплатно. Я даже на portal.azure зарегистрировалась и там искала, вопрос все задают тот же, а на ответ ссылку на сайт Визуал Студио ставят.

На платформе DevAzure создала проект, получается вносить правки от имени аккаунта DevAzure так же создавать ветки и вносить изменения, Visual Studio реагирует корректно

Пришлашаю пользователя, пользователь получает ссылку проходит по сслыке, копирует проект, и получает сообщение `TF30063: You are not authorized to access`

- для информации и создатель и приглашенный пользователь это я, то есть с одного и того же поста, но под разными почтами (акаунт Майкрософт)

что мне делать, чтобы от лица приглашенного пользователя получить существующий репозиторий с платформы DevAzure?

***Обновленно.** У меня получается вносить изменения от имени приглашенного пользователя, но переодически выдает ошибку `Git failed with a fatal error. repository 'ссылка на репозиторий' not found` или еще что то другое (зависит ли это от того, что я перелогиниваюсь с одного юзера на другой и Система/Vs/MsDevAzure не успевает понять там может кеш или что)

Мой вопрос, нужно ли платить, чтоб все работало без ошибок постоянных там или может установить ВизуальСтудио платную версию ?
кто пользовался подскажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете проверить уровень доступа этих пользователей в разделе «Настройки организации» -> «Пользователи» -> «Уровень доступа».

Администраторы могут выполнить шаги [управления пользователями](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#manage-users), чтобы изменить уровни доступа пользователей.

Кстати, для первых 5 пользователей Basic бесплатен.

[вопрос задала на сайте](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-devops-users-cant-see-repos-even-t/10305590)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]и проверив оказалось, что  Basic был не у всех, а еще в этот же день право не присваевается, надо день подождать, чтоб обновилась информация

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145265/discussion-on-answer-by-dev18-devazure----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.